# get store data using store url multi store magento2

Tags: magento2

I have multi store environment with three stores,

1. us.abc.com
2. ca.abc.com
3. uk.abc.com

having respective websites and store views.

I want to get store data like store code, store id, store website etc. by store URL "us.abc.com"
is there any function that I can pass the store URL and get the data of store?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the store code from the URL using below method

```
$storeUrl = 'us.abc.com';
$storeCode = strtok($storeUrl, '.');
echo $storeCode; // us
```

Now you can get the store details using the store code

```
protected $storeRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Api\StoreRepositoryInterface $storeRepository
) {
    $this->storeRepository= $storeRepository;
}
    $storeUrl = 'us.abc.com';
    $storeCode = strtok($storeUrl, '.');
    // echo $storeCode; // us

    $store = $this->storeRepository->get($storeCode);
    echo $store->getId(); // this is the store ID
    echo $store->getName();
    echo $store->getWebsiteId();
```